# Can I freeze left over Shake & Bake coating mix after it's used?

Tags: food-safety, freezing

After coating my chicken with Shake & Bake, I transfer the remainder into a container and freeze it until I need it again. Is this an unsafe practice? I figure if I'm freezing meat so it won't spoil, then the Shake & Bake coating mix should be safe in the freezer until I need it again.

Answer (score 1):

You can freeze any shake&bake coating if it has not been used.I would think there would be a strong possibility of bacterial contamination (which is not killed in the freezing process.)

Answer (score 0):

it's not really necessary to freeze the coating mix; it should stay good for awhile as long as it is tightly covered. However, do NOT re-use any mix that has come into contact with the chicken, ESPECIALLY raw.